# What music genre would most Noir-esque jazz fall under?

Tags: genre, jazz, tempo

I've been trying to gather up a library of music that fits within Noir films, I know most of it is some section of jazz, Ibrahim Maalouf is an example of an artist who has many tracks with the tone and tempo I'm looking for, I'm finding it hard to find albums and other artists.

Examples:

- [Andrew Hale — L.A. Noire + RainyMood [Extended]](https://youtu.be/WDippeD3pj8)
- [Jason Parker Quartet - Tree of Life](https://youtu.be/FIs1kokP4wc)
- [Jazz Noir and Jazz Noir Music: 2 Hours Jazz Noir Playlist collection of Jazz Noir](https://youtu.be/2ZRE0Fvisyc)

For anyone looking, while there doesn't seem to be a good source, there is a musician who composed a one hour set of Jazz Noir, [Dr. Saxlove](https://drsaxlove.com/jazz-noir).

Comment: Can you add some examples? I can't exactly figure out what you mean...

Comment: @Bebs Added examples to post

Comment: Thanks... so I think Tetsujin is correct.

Comment: @Bebs see latest comment on Tetusjin's post

Comment: Thanks, but you said you are not satisfied with Tetsujin's answer "Jazz Noir" but then you post an example of what you like called "Jazz Noir"... maybe I misunderstood what exactly is your question...?

Comment: @Bebs I was disagreeing with the compilation CD that Tetsujin linked as it had a majority of more upbeat, loud, and fast music while I'm looking for the slower mellower music.  Jazz Noir doesn't seem work as a genre that is used by music catalogs.  I linked the album I found as a best fit for anyone looking for similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Jazz Noir**

I can't find any specific authoritative reference, Wikipedia etc, but Reddit has it tagged as

> So what is jazznoir?
>   It’s mysterious, melancholy and menacing music
>   by swingin' sax men and sultry sirens for hardboiled hepcats and leggy
>   lookers. It’s late-night listening for luckless losers, and the
>   soundtrack to strolls under street lights on foggy nights.

Google has a lot of hits for 'jazz noir', including on Amazon, a 3-CD set - [Jazz Noir [3CD Box Set]](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Jazz-Noir-3CD-Box-Set/dp/B00Q34WUN2) - pretty cheap. I did notice it starts with Peter Gunn... & though I can see why they would include it, I don't think it quite fits. I haven't checked through the entire track list for 'appropriate to theme' though.

Comment: Does it refer to Jazz music played by african-american musicians?

Comment: I never considered the ethnic origins of the players [nor are they usually listed in the credits, as it's usually 'a band'] - the composers aren't of a single ethnicity & I would doubt the players are either.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure because in French, it would refer to that (Noir means Black). So my question persists... I don't see what kind of music is discussed here. Do you have some examples?

Comment: You can play 30s of every song on the Amazon link. Noir, btw in this context refers to a movie style.

Comment: I know, but at the same time you said that you don't think it fits so I'm confused...

Comment: I only said I didn't think Peter Gunn was a good fit for the genre; I think it's a bit 'surf' though as it's from a noir-esque TV series I can see why they did include it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I purchased the CD set, and a lot of the music is very upbeat.  So I was looking more for the slower drawn out sounds and that's where I thought it may be a subset of jazz.
The first song in the first link I provided is what I'm looking for if such a category exists.
That is long notes on wind instruments, very slow tempo, brush used on the snare drum, etc.